# Split string and display first character

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I need to break out the name field to show last name and first initial in separate fields.

So far, I can break out the LastName, FirstName, but is there a way I can only select the first name initial?

```
     regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as LastName,
     regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as FirstName
```

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `left()` function is not supported by Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused didn't see "oracle" tag. So these code snippets will only work with SQL Server:

You can do this by using standard string functions.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @name = 'Tom Sheldon'

-- you can use this instead of regular expressions
SELECT RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)+3) + ' ' + LEFT(@name, 1) + '.' AS name
```

Returns:

| name |
| --- |
| Sheldon T. |

and

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @name = 'Tom Sheldon'

-- you can use this instead of regular expressions
SELECT
    RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)+3) AS LastName,
    LEFT(@name, 1) AS FirstName
```

Returns:

| LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| Sheldon | T |

Comment: Thanks, but RIGHT/LEFT is not supported by Oracle DB.

Comment: Oops. i'm so confused. Didn't see "oracle" tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SUBSTR with the resuklt of the regexp_substr

> ```
> with rws as (
>   select 'lastname,firstname' str from dual
> )
>  SELECT     regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as LastName,
>  
>      SUBSTR(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, 2),1,1)  as FirstNameinitial
>   from rws
> ```

> ```
> LASTNAME | FIRSTNAMEINITIAL
> :------- | :---------------
> lastname | f
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd6ed53c5fa42685a239a2be5e18d824)*

Answer (score 0):

Hah!

This might be inelegant, but it worked:

```
substr ( (regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1, 2)),2,1  ) as FirstName
```

I started the substring at 2, b/c there was a space between the comma and the first name. I now have two columns: LastName, FirstInit

Comment: i was 6 minutes faster

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the separator is a comma, and using old-school `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()`, this version will allow for the possibility that there may be zero or more spaces following the comma:

```
WITH nrow AS (
    SELECT 'Lastname, Firstname' AS pers_name
    FROM   dual
)
    SELECT SUBSTR (pers_name, 1, INSTR (pers_name, ',') - 1) AS last_name,
           SUBSTR (LTRIM (SUBSTR (pers_name, INSTR (pers_name, ',') + 1)), 1, 1) AS first_init
    FROM   nrow
/
```